# Sorting dynamoDB query results using secondary local index

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with the following fields in dynamoDB:

1. primary key: reference_number
2. sort key: user_id
3. local secondary index on: isEligible
4. local secondary index on: score

I want to fetch all documents corresponding to a reference_number with isEligible as true. I am doing this using a query, with a range condition on isEligible field. I now want the results of this query to be returned in order sorted by score field. Is there a way I can achieve this?
All of this is being done in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently modeled, no.

If had a LSI with a composite sort key, ex:
`"true#85"`
`"true#100"`
`"false#45"`

You could then use a `begins_with` in your Query().

Comment: I think using the BEGINS_WITH operator is my best bet in this case

Answer (score 0):

Is your secondary index just on one Key? you can assign them both keys as well - say pk: isEligible, sk: score.

Then a query against the that index and pk == True will return all the true scores in order.

**EDIT** my mistake. LSI vs GSI. So my answer would be a GSI would be the best for you, without having to make another concatted field... as long as you dont make too many. If you find yourself making a ton of GSIs then re-evaluate how you have your data stored. Likely its stored in a way that is better for a SQL /Relational Database not a noSQL table. Access Patterns is your key, not storage patterns.

Comment: I created a local secondary key, so in this case, pk=reference number, sk=score. Do you mean I should create a global secondary index? If I do that, can I query on pk + global pk + global sk?

Comment: You only query with two keys, if using a GSI it's the GSI pk+sk.

Comment: @Charles yes and you can set your PK and SK to *any* attribute in your items. so you could set an inverse index  where you flip your PK and Sk (a very common practice) or you can create a new one.

---- baggy696 yes, i guess I do - I did not realize LSI were just one - my mistake (everything ive read and heard has been to not use LSI and just make a GSI - or figure out a better schema where you dont need either)